# creating a jQuery Event Listener for when custom function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function, let call it: myFunction, that I use a lot.  Most of the time, I don't care when it's called.  However, sometimes, it would be nice to know when it is called so that I can perform certain actions.  Is there a way that I can, without editing myFunction, create a listener in jQuery so that when myFunction is done, I can call another function?

for example:

```
<script>
var foo = "foo";
function myFunction() {
    foo += "bar";
}
function afterMyFunction() {
    alert(foo);
}

$(function() {
    #some sort of listener for when myFunction is done --- ???#

    myFunction();
});
</script>
```

I would want, when the page loads, for there to be an alert that simply says "foobar".  This is obviously a simplified example, but it gets my point across... I hope.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.callbacks/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery calling a callback function in a custom function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866787/jquery-calling-a-callback-function-in-a-custom-function)

Answer (score 0):

Without editing the function, I don't know how.
But with editing you can trigger a custom event like this :

JS

```
var foo = "foo";
function myFunction() {
    foo += "bar";
    $('body').trigger('myFunctionDone');
}
function afterMyFunction() {
    alert(foo);
}

$(function() {
    $('body').on('myFunctionDone',function(){
        console.log('done');
    });

    myFunction();
});
```

Comment: I knew about that, i just wasn't sure if there was a way to do what i asked in the original post.  Like i said, most of the time, i don't care when the function is called... but on the rare occasions that i do, it'd be nice to be able to add a listener.  Thanks for the response!